# How do I turn the output "__main__.Book object" into a string?

Tags: python, string, object

When I want to print my object I only get:

```
>>> LIB.get_book("Synantrop")
<__main__.Book object at 0x102321b50>
```

What do I need to do to get it as a string instead? 
I have tried

```
def __repr__( self ):
    return "Book(%d,%r)" % (self.title,self.year,self.author)
```

and

```
def __str__( self ):
    return "%2d%s" % (self.title,self.year,self.author)
```

but it doesn't work!
I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The interactive prompt always shows the `repr` string.

Answer (score 3):

Your `__str__` and `__repr__` should work, provided:

1. you define them in the correct class (`Book`);
2. you fix the errors whereby the format specifiers don't match the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(LIB.get_book("Synantrop"))
```

should work. **str** function is only called when you pass the object to print. If you don't, it's just gonna return whatever value get_book returns